# "download.file" Incomplete and inconsistent downloads

Tags: r, csv, download

Am trying to understand why I am having inconsistent results downloading CSV files from a website archive.   Don't know if the problem is at my end, the other side or just failed communications in between.   Any suggestions are welcomed.

Using a R script to automate the downloading of CSV files by month and year from the HYCOM archives for analysis.   The script generated the following URL trying URL 'http://ncss.hycom.org/thredds/ncss/GLBu0.08/reanalysis/3hrly?var=salinity&var=water_temp&var=water_u&var=water_v&latitude=13.875&longitude=-72.25&time_start=2012-05-01T00:00:00Z&time_end=2012-05-31T21:00:00Z&vertCoord=&accept=csv'

Running `download.file` successfully obtains the file about half the time, otherwise fails.  Any suggestions are welcomed.   The images below shows the failed run.  Successful run is below.

Successful Log

```
#download one month of data
MM = '05'
LastDay = ndays(paste(year,MM,'01',sep="-"))
H1 = paste( as shown in image)
H2 = '-01T00:00:00Z&time_end='
#H3 = 'T21:00:00Z&timeStride=1&vertCoord=&accept=csv'
H3 = 'T21:00:00Z&vertCoord=&accept=csv'
HtmlLink <- paste(H1,year,"-",MM,H2,year,"-",MM,"-",LastDay,H3,sep="")
dest = paste("../data/",year,MM,".csv",sep="")
download.file(url =HtmlLink ,destfile=dest,cacheOK=FALSE, method="auto")

trying URL 'as shown in image'
Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' length unknown
..................................................
................downloaded 666 KB

user   system  elapsed 
28.278    6.605 5201.421
```

[LOG OF FAILED RUN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xjN4.png)

Comment: You might try `"curl"` or `"wget"` for `method`, though make sure they're installed first.

Comment: will also look into curl and wget.  Since I can FTP multiple files, I may end up downloading the full dataset which is about about 4T of data for 4 years instead of letting the slow server on the other end extract the data.

Comment: Since "http" won't load on my mac for some reason despite attempting to install it from multiple sites and also local install (my installer says that a windows version was downloaded from the OS X link), I am testing curl_download from curl library.   I had 30 to 50% failures with download.files and transfer times on the order of 2000 seconds.  On a very small sample, the download times are about half.   Will report more after I run off a larger sample.

Comment: httr is one of the most popular CRAN pkgs of all time. I can only imagine how truly misconfigured your macOS system is to not be able to install it.

Comment: beats me.  I rebooted, restarted R and it worked.  Never happened before with any package.  Still, thanks for suggesting Curl.  it works great.

Answer (score 2):

You can/should turn the following into a function accepting parameters and replace the hardcoded values with said params (I used `httr:::parse_query()` to make the `list`):

```
library(httr)

URL <- "http://ncss.hycom.org/thredds/ncss/GLBu0.08/reanalysis/3hrly"

params <- list(var = "salinity", 
               var = "water_temp", 
               var = "water_u", 
               var = "water_v", 
               latitude = "13.875", 
               longitude = "-72.25", 
               time_start = "2012-05-01T00:00:00Z", 
               time_end = "2012-05-31T21:00:00Z", 
               vertCoord = "", 
               accept = "csv")

dest_file <- "filename"

res <- GET(url=URL, 
           query=params,
           timeout(360), 
           write_disk(dest_file, overwrite=TRUE), 
           verbose())

warn_for_status(res)
```

You can (eventually) remove the `verbose()` from that `GET` call, but it's helpful during debugging.

The main issue is that this server is   s   l   o   w   and times out before the transfer is complete. Even the value of `360` might not be enough (you'll need to experiment).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the timeout and verbose parameters.   I'll see if these help.   Verbose may provide more information than proc.time which had not been useful as shown below.
Failed:    user  system elapsed 
               0.389   0.123  61.883 
Success   user   system  elapsed 
                12.681    3.070 2113.788 
FAILED    user   system  elapsed 
                13.136    3.189 2180.353 
FAILED     user  system elapsed 
                 0.828   0.217 128.000

Comment: DARN.   httr is not available for OS X.   will look into curl and wget.

Comment: It most certainly is available on OS X.

Comment: The install manager in R 3.3.1 returns an error "it is not possible to install binary packages from a remote repository".   I've tried installing locally from downloaded copies from several repositories without luck.   Downloaded the tgz file and was told by the installer that the file was not an OS X dataset.  "devtools::install_github("hadley/httr")" returned path errors.

Comment: Downloaded the OSX tgz file again.  Upon install, got the following error: file ‘/Users/schaudt/R_packages/httr_1.2.1.tgz’ is not an OS X binary package

Comment: i run macOS. thousands of other R users do as well and use the httr package. `install.packages("httr")` works perfectly for us. what's unique about your macOS install? httr also has [dozens of reverse dependencies](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/httr/) and has passed all macOS [CRAN checks](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/checks/check_flavors.html#r-devel-osx-x86_64-clang).

Comment: Beats me.  Just a plain vanilla of 3.3.1 GUI 1.68 Mavericks on OS X 10.10.5.  The R install manager returned the above error message when I tried it from R.  Using a local download, the installer returned the note that the latest version of the OS X file that I twice downloaded from CRAN was not an OS X file.  Perhaps the files are being corrupted in download or that file is corrupted on the website.    I'll try the older version once I get done with downloading the data from the website using curl.  Am booting up a windows box to look at this further.

Comment: HTTR just installed without a problem on a Windows 7Pro box using the package manager (R 3.1.0).    Will examine the file that I downloaded from CRAN to see if it is a windows or OS X file or simply corrupted.

Comment: rebooted the machine, restarted R and http installed without a hitch.  Get error "could not find function "write_file".  Installed readr.  Still get error about not finding "write_file".   removed that from get statement and am testing GET to see how it compares with curl.   Thanks for the help.  Will update my answer when I get done testing.

Comment: After finishing the data download from the HYCOM server, rebooting and restarting R, I was able to install httr without a problem.  Perhaps the install procedure ran into timing problems due to the long data download.   Installed httr and readr.  Running your script produced the following error.s <- GET(url=URL, 
+            query=params,
+            timeout(360), 
+            write_file(dest_file, overwrite=TRUE), 
+            verbose())
Error in write_file(dest_file, overwrite = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (overwrite = TRUE)   Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to all for the help.  The suggestion by hrbrmstr appears to be an elegant answer and I look forwards to testing it.   However, I was unable to install a working copy using the program manager.  Installation from a local download also failed since  R complained that the OS X version that I downloaded from CRAN was a windows version, not OS X. Yes, I repeated the download several times to make sure I had the right package.

As suggested by Cyrus Mohammadian, I tried the procedures in the curl library.
Running the same URL, download.file transfers failed about 50% of the time.   Using curl reduced the transfer times from 2000 seconds to 1000 seconds with no failures in 12 tries.

```
   ## calculate number of days in month 
    ndays <- function(d) {
    last_days <- 28:31
    rev(last_days[which(!is.na( 
                             as.Date( paste( substr(d, 1, 8), 
                                             last_days, sep = ''), 
                                      '%Y-%m-%d')))])[1] }
    nlat = 13.875
    elon = -72.25
    #download one month of data
    year = 2008
    MM = '01'
    LastDay = ndays(paste(year,MM,'01',sep="-"))
    H1 = paste('http://ncss.hycom.org/thredds/ncss/GLBu0.08/reanalysis/3hrly?
   var=salinity&var=water_temp&var=water_u&var=water_v&latitude=',
   nlat,'&longitude=', elon,'&time_start=',sep="")
   H2 = '-01T00:00:00Z&time_end='
   H3 = 'T21:00:00Z&timeStride=1&vertCoord=&accept=csv'
   HtmlLink <- paste(H1,year,"-",MM,H2,year,"-",MM,"-",LastDay,H3,sep="")
   dest = paste("../data/",year,MM,".csv",sep="")
   curl_download(url =HtmlLink ,destfile=dest,quiet=FALSE, mode="wb")
```